# AngularJS Data Binding is not happening

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I am just playing around with AngularJS and I wrote a small piece of code which I have shared [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2PMFdAqvqxVr5V9o7CcP?p=preview). But for some reason, the binding of data doesnt happen. Here is the HTML and JS code for those who do not want to go to the plucker site.

**first.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="firstApp">
<head>
    <title>First Angular JS</title>
    <script src="/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/first.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="FirstController">
        <span>Name:</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="first">    
        <input type="text" ng-model="last">
        <button ng-click='updateMessage()'>Message</button>
        <hr>{{heading + message}}
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**first.js**

```
var firstApp = angular.module('firstApp',[]);
firstApp.controller = ('FirstController',function($scope)
{
  $scope.first = "Some";
  $scope.last = "one";
  $scope.heading = "Message: ";
  $scope.updateMessage = function()
    {
      $scope.message = 'Hello' + $scope.first + ' ' + $scope.last + '!';
    };
  });
```

In the HTML, I am using express to redirect calls to its appropriate places

**node_server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static('./static')).
    use('/images',express.static('./images')).
    use('/lib',express.static('./lib/angular-1.2.22'));
app.listen(8080);
```

The output is showing {{message + heading}}. Does anyone have any ideas why this wouldnt work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the way you're declaring your controller.

You have:

```
firstApp.controller = ('FirstController',function($scope) ...
```

It should be:

```
firstApp.controller('FirstController', function($scope) ...
```

Comment: Thank you rabaznaz. I spent a lot of time poring over the code for this one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

firstApp.controller('FirstController', ['$scope', function($scope) { ...

[Doc's for controller in Angular](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)